# What preposition should I choose in this sentence? and the order of words is a little bit confusing

Tags: grammar, prepositions

1: the inexorable increase in the size of the economy of China.
2: the inexorable increase of China in the size of the economy.
3: the inexorable increase of China on the size of the economy.
by the way, should it be "the economy" or just "economy"?
Thx(●'◡'●)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 1 is correct and idiomatic. 2 and  3 gives rise to the question "whose economy? Guatemala's? New York's? Gaming industry's?"

1 sounds natural with the definite article "the".

1 can be rephrased as

"the inexorable increase in the size of China's(or Chinese) economy." without the need of any article.